# sbt lock SNAPSHOT dependency

Tags: scala, sbt

I use sbt-lock plugin and want to download latest snapshot, including -SNAPSHOT version. When I write in my build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "org.consensusresearch" %% "scorex-basics" % "1.2.+"
```

and run `sbt relock` it find only version 1.2.6, while 1.2.7-SNAPSHOT  release is available. How to set up sbt to load `1.2.7-SNAPSHOT` version?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a known issue and a lot of people are struggling [example](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/321).

The only workaround I found that works consistently (i.e. after trying clean, cleanAll, update, etc. to no luck) was to target and delete, using a custom task in build.sbt, the dependencies in Ivy cache and then rebuild

```
lazy val nukeIvy = taskKey[Unit]("Execute rm -rf ~/ivy2/cache script")
nukeIvy := {
  val s: TaskStreams = streams.value
  val shell: Seq[String] =
    if (sys.props("os.name").contains("Windows")) Seq("cmd", "/c")
    else Seq("bash", "-c")
  val removeIvy: Seq[String]          = shell :+ "rm -rf ~/.ivy2/cache/com.explori"
  val removeCommonCodecs: Seq[String] = shell :+ "rm -rf ~/.ivy2/cache/commons-codec"
  s.log.info("nuking ivy cache...")
  if ((removeIvy !) == 0 && (removeCommonCodecs !) == 0) {
    s.log.success("remove com.explori from ivy cache successful!")
  } else {
    throw new IllegalStateException("cleanIvy failed!")
  }
}
```